# What is the cause of singularity in phase response curve of human sleep and bright light?

Tags: sleep, circadian-rhythms, chronobiology

I have no background in science as I am a computer programmer, but I am trying to get information on phase response curves, human sleep and exposure to bright light as I am trying to get to grips with a possible diagnosis of delayed sleep phase disorder.

[image]

The point marked *phase delay* is typically where someone would go to sleep and they would typically wake a couple hours after the peak marked *phase advance*. What is the physiological process that cause the move from *delay* to *advance* via the point marked *singularity*? In other words, why does light cause a delay initially but then cause an advance?